# jQuery add ascending numbers to ID

Tags: jquery, indexing

I have a form that generates divs. I have applied a base ID to each div but I need to add numbers to them to differentiate between them.

I have read up on Index and looked at other example but I can't get it to work here, it seemed to throw a wobbly when I put the num variable in. Anyway I took out the code that was breaking it.

Here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/BMX4J/13/

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`val()` is not correct here. `val()` is for input elements.

When you do:

```
var newDiv = $('<div id="toggleshow" ......
```

Change it to:

```
var newDiv = $('<div id="toggleshow_' + num++ + '"
```

And do `var num = 0;` outside of the function.

Comment: Thanks very much, this works well, but I am getting different numbers for #toggleshow and #show. I need these numbers to be the same, any idea how to acheive this? The updated fiddle is here, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/BMX4J/18/

Comment: Hi, I just made another var for num for the otherdiv and it works hundreds now, thanks

Comment: @ClintonGreen you can just do `num` instead of `num++` in one of them.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to make every id in the created `div` unique by adding a counter of sorts to a base id.  If so the easiest way to do this two use two functions.  Have the counter be in the outer function and let the inner function be the click handler which captures the counter and reuses it.

```
$(".add_menu_item").click((function() {
  var id = 0;
  return function () {
    var value = $(this).prev().val();
    if (value.length) {
      var newDiv = $('<div id="toggleshow" class="div_menu_button"></div>');
      var showDiv = $('<div id="show"' + id + '">Bob Lawbob</div>');
      $('#created_buttons_list').append(newDiv.val(value).text(value));
      newDiv.wrap("<li></li>");
      newDiv.after(showDiv);
      id++;
    }
  }
})());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BMX4J/17/

Comment: Thanks that sounds great but I checked out the fiddle and the ID names were not changing, it was adding -- 1"="" -- to the div

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the child count of the container to append ascending numbers to new elements:

```
var count = $("#created_buttons_list").children().length;

newDiv.attr("id", newDiv.attr("id") + "_" + count.toString());
```